# mv command not working on mac

Tags: makefile, mv

Here is the part of the makefile that is giving me issues:

```
-@mv -f -t ./ $(LIBPATH)/userfiles/*
```

When I run the makefile on Ubuntu it works fine however when running on my Mac I get the following error:

```
mv: illegal option -- t usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

The -t flag is not defined in the man pages of my mac so I'm wondering how I can get around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the destination at the end like how `mv` is normally used:

```
-@mv -f $(LIBPATH)/userfiles/* .
```

You are allowed to have multiple sources (such as the expanded wildcard here).  The last argument is the destination.  The `-t` flag is just a way to change this ordering if you have to for some reason, and (as you discovered) it is not always available.

Answer (score 0):

Install [coreutils](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils) by typing the following command in the terminal:

```
brew install coreutils
```

Commands also provided by macOS and the commands dir, dircolors, vdir have been installed with the prefix "g".

If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH with:

```
    PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Reference:
[coreutils - Homebrew Formulae](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils)